# How to emit signal, when user changes row with keyboard arrows in tableView?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have **two tableViews**, in one I load album names, in the other I want to load tracks from selected album.

Problem is simple: I can't use signals such as activated, mouse clicked, etc. I want to change stuff in the tracks tableView simply by the highlighting row in the album names tableView.

Summary: emit signal when user changes row and find out on which row he is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Handling selection of items](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/model-view-programming.html#handling-selections-of-items) section in the Qt Model/Views documentation.

In essence, what you need to use is your QTableView's [selection model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qitemselectionmodel.html) which has signals for when the selection changes in the table. You access the view's selection model via it's [selectionModel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel) member function.

Comment: You might be calling that too early. Make sure your view is set up before you call selectionModel().

Comment: thanks for your time, i cant yet vote up ur answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok,so i have solved this problem like this:

First, you must obtain QItemSelectionModel !after! the table was filled:

QItemSelectionModel *select = ui->tableView->selectionModel();

Then connect SIGNAL "selectionChanged" with you own SLOT function:

connect(select, SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)),
        this, SLOT(change_table()));